# Checkting all the insert queries in a snowflake table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Is there a way where I can check all the insert queries that have been executed by different users for a particular table in snowflake?

Comment: Look at the schema `snowflake.account_usage`. In there you'll find a view for `query_history`. That will get you all the insert statements for the trailing 365 days. You can join that view to the `access_history` view in the same schema. The `base_objects_accessed` will specify which table had the insert, so you can filter the insert statements to only the ones that inserted into that specific table. You could also just use a filter on the SQL text to look for the table name. It may get a few false positives but it may be easier to write and faster to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) and [QUERY_ACCESS_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html) views in the [ACCOUNT_USAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html) schema of the [SNOWFLAKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-db.html) database.

**Notes:**

- QUERY_ACCESS_HISTORY requires Enterprise Edition or higher.
- You will need the [ACCOUNTADMIN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html#using-the-accountadmin-role) role, or [have been granted privileges to the SNOWFLAKE database](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#label-enabling-usage-for-other-roles).

```
select 
      ah.query_id
    , ah.query_start_time
    , ah.user_name
    , qh.query_type
    , f1.value:"objectName"::varchar as table_name
    , f1.value:"objectId"::int as table_id
    , qh.query_text
from access_history ah
inner join query_history qh on qh.query_id = ah.query_id
    , lateral flatten(ah.objects_modified) f1
where f1.value:"objectDomain"::varchar = 'Table'
      and qh.query_type in ('INSERT', 'MULTI_TABLE_INSERT', 'MERGE', 'UPDATE');
      -- Enter your fully qualified table name below
      and f1.value:"objectName"::varchar = 'FAILOVER_TEST.PROD.SUPPLIER';
```

The output will look like the table below. Take note of the `OBJECT_ID` column, as in this example it indicates that these actions happened on different *versions* of the table. (ex. `create or replace table...` )

| QUERY_ID | QUERY_START_TIME | USER_NAME | QUERY_TYPE | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_ID | QUERY_TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01a50975-0602-2593-006b-c1830031d242 | 2022-06-18 16:37:20.731 -0400 | BOB | INSERT | FAILOVER_TEST.PROD.SUPPLIER | 287776 | insert into failover_test.prod.SUPPLIER select * from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.SUPPLIER |
| 01a5097b-0602-24ff-006b-c1830031b37e | 2022-06-18 16:43:44.413 -0400 | JILL | INSERT | FAILOVER_TEST.PROD.SUPPLIER | 286738 | insert into failover_test.prod.SUPPLIER select * from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.SUPPLIER |